# Cannot select an element based on its tag name using selenium web driver for C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Web Driver for C# and the browser that I am using is Google Chrome. When I try to get the inner html (text) of an element which is demonstrated in the HTML code piece below, I get **"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span"}"** error.

```
<a class="profile-link" href="#">
    <span dir="ltr">
        <span aria-hidden="true">FirstName LastName</span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">xxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

The C# code that I am using to get the span conatining the FirsName and LastName is:

```
string result = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("profile-link")).Last().FindElement(By.TagName("span")).FindElement(By.TagName("span")).Text;
```

Also, when I try to get to FirstName and LastName by using `FindElements` and `Last()` instead of `FindElement`, I get the **"Sequence contains no elements"**

In this case the code that I am using is:

```
string result = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("profile-link")).Last().FindElements(By.TagName("span")).Last().FindElements(By.TagName("span")).First().Text + ",";
```

How can I fix this issue and get the inner HTML of the span containing FirstName and LastName?

Comment: Can you share the link to that page? And if possibly all your relevant code

Comment: Does `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("profile-link")).Last()` return you the Anchor element you expect?

Comment: @rene Yes it does. Actually, cruisepandey and Prophet answered the question. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `XPath`, or `css`. Below I have tried with **XPath**

```
//a[@class='profile-link']/descendant::span[2]
```

In code :

```
string result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='profile-link']/descendant::span[2]")).Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing a wait / delay before accessing that element.
Try adding

```
WebDriver.WaitForElementIsVisible(By.Xpath("(//a[@class='profile-link')])[last()]"));
```

and after that using your code.
Also, I'm not sure about the way you are finding that element.
CSS selector or XPath seems to me to be more reliable here.
So, please try this:

```cs
WebDriver.WaitForElementIsVisible(By.Xpath("(//a[@class='profile-link')])[last()]"));
string result = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//a[@class='profile-link')])[last()]/span/span")).Text;
```